# Hibernate HQL is failing on alias ordering

Tags: hibernate

I have this query in hql:

```
select sum(settledPricePerDownloadExpense),avg(settledPricePerDownloadExpense),sum(siteIdCount) as ct,sum(settledPricePerDownloadExpense) 
from PpdCampaignReporting  where id.ppdCampaignReportDate between 'Wed May 11 00:00:00 EDT 2011' and 'Thu May 12 23:59:59 EDT 2011' And id.ppdCampaignActionTypeId in (1, 2, 3) And id.ppdCampaign.ppdCampaignId in (62,63,82,83,84,95,97) 
group by id.ppdCampaignActionTypeId,id.siteId order by ct
```

The error I am getting back is this:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'ct'.
```

Which I don't understand since I have sum(siteIdCount) as ct

Comment: are we looking at hql or straight up sql in the query above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordering by alias defined in select clause is a known bug in Hibernate. It was fixed in 3.6.x branch, so make sure you're using the latest production release.

Be aware, though, that there have been incompatible changes made with regards to 3.5 and earlier versions (dealing with user types and lobs are the two major areas) so you need to be careful when upgrading.

Alternatively, you can either use "order by 1" (if your RDBMS supports it; I'm not sure about SQL Server) or order by `expression` (e.g. `order by sum(siteIdCount)` in your case).

P.S. Group by alias is still broken.